# SQL Server: replace by NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT REPLACE('hello', 'e', NULL) 
-- returns NULL

SELECT REPLACE('hello', '5', NULL) 
-- also returns NULL -- here I'd expect it does nothing since there is no '5' in 'hello'
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clearly states:

> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

So the behavior is explained.

Is there a workaround, meaning if a pattern is found in a string like 'e' in hello ; a NULL value is emitted?

Comment: If the pattern is _not_ found in `hello`, then what should the output be?

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for well over 2 years; you really should be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ; if it is not found, it should return hello. If it is found, it should return NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `REPLACE` isn't what you are after. One method instead would be using a `CASE` and a `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 'hello' NOT LIKE '%5%' THEN 'hello' END;
```

Alternatively you could use `CHARINDEX`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('5','hello') = 0 THEN 'hello' END;
```

Comment: thanks! sometimes you're starting at a problem and forget alternatives... :-) many thanks for this!!!

Comment: You're welcome, @TimBer . If it answers the question, please do consider marking it as the solution so that future users know the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried ; but you cannot force the result to be NULL in a case :(

Comment: What do you mean, @TimBer ? Both the above will return `NULL` if the search character is found. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7db5b2c81fb7586c86a53c343e54e44a)